# Why is my mint plant growing new leaves that appears web like

Tags: leaves, mint

I recently bought this mint plant from walmart and I repotted it in my own pot. it had been doing good until I accidentally left it in the sun too long and it all shriveled. however just after 8 hours of watering it revived and has been doing well. two/three weeks later (now) i’m noticing new leaves growing but very spongy or web looking. does anyone know? I googled and saw stuff about possible mites/spiders but i’m not sure that it’s what it is.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From what's visible in your photo, the newer upper leaves look fine and your plant's prospects look good.  It's possible the damage on the lower leaves is from lack of water but it looks more like some insect had a meal.  If the plant is outdoors the lineup of potential suspects is long, but any stressed plant is more likely to be attacked than a thriving one.  Spider mites are bright red, often on the underside of leaves, tend to move around energetically, and while tiny, are visible to the naked eye.  Seen from the top, the damage they leave is very fine speckling (google spider mite damage images).  So I don't think they are eating the mint.  I'd keep an eye on the plant and see if maybe with regular watering it will simply outgrow the rough last couple weeks it has had.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely leaf miner damage. The adult lands on a leaf and pierces the leaf surface to lay eggs inside the leaf among the soft tissues between the top and bottom hard layers of the leaf. The larvae emerge inside the leaf and start tunnelling their way through the soft material. Once the inside is destroyed the top and bottom layers dry out and collapse leaving holes. Note how the leaf miner larvae have a problem passing through the leaf veins so parts of the leaf remain functional.

Leaf miners are known to attack mint plants. The best we can do is to put the plant in good high light conditions to harden off the leaves so the adults can't lay their eggs, and moderate the fertilizer for the same reason. Pick off any signs of new tunnelling as you see it to interrupt their life cycle.